# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, constraints

I know that this question has already been asked, but I still can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using the framework Laravel.

I have 2 tables (Users and Locations). When I want to create a User, I get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`festival_aid`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `fk_users_locations1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`location_id`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `users` (`user_id`,
>   `user_email`, `location_id`) values (?, ?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 =>
>   '1', 1 => 'test@hotmail.com', 2 => '1', ))

Table Users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`users` (
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_locked` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `location_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_locations1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`)
    REFERENCES `festival_aid`.`locations` (`location_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table Locations

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `festival_aid`.`locations` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`locations` (
  `location_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_latitude` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `location_longitude` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `location_desc` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `location_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Migration User

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('user_email');
            $table->timestamp('user_created');
            $table->timestamp('user_modified');
            $table->timestamp('user_deleted');
            $table->timestamp('user_lastlogin');
            $table->timestamp('user_locked');

            $table->foreign('location_id')
                ->references('id')->on('locations');
            //->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Migration Location

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('locations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->primary('location_id');
            $table->float('location_latitude');
            $table->float('location_longitude');
            $table->string('location_desc');
            $table->string('location_type');
        });
    }
```

Model User

```
public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Location');
    }
```

Model Location

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User');
    }
```

Controller

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array('user_email' => 'required|unique:users|email');

        $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($v->passes())
        {
            $user = new User();
            $location = new Location();

            $user->user_email = $input['user_email'];
            //$user->location_id = $input['location_id'];

            $location->location_latitude = $input['location_latitude'];
            $location->location_longitude = $input['location_longitude'];

            $user->save();
            $location->save();
    }
```

I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Obviously there is something wrong with the foreign key.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A user row needs a reference to a valid location. 
That location must be available before the user is saved. 
So, first save the location and then save the user and uncomment the `$user->location_id` line and you are done.

Comment: that is strange but in my case I do have rows in constraint table before inserting but it still throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

Those Developers who face this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `user_id`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (rao, 1, sflkkjk, 2016-03-01 20:45:32, 2016-03-01 20:45:32))
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `user_id`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (rao, 1, sflkkjk, 2016-03-01 20:45:32, 2016-03-01 20:45:32))

First Save the user record of user then try to insert record then easily inserted into the database.

**KEY POINT**

Two Tables: one is article and other is user. A user has many articles but no article has many users. So foreign key is shifted toward the article table. If user table has no record then you face the same error seen earlier.

By doing this we can easily solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If user table has no record then you face the same error seen earlier.
you may set any default value before running migration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).