# What prevents me from adding a row with foreign key value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

```
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bpr`.`trips`, CONSTRAINT `trips_driver_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`driver_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

is the error.

**Adding a row, manually, through MySQL works fine. If I do it through my application - nope.**

The `id` that I am trying to insert is correct (it exists and is an integer). I checked the foreign keys and stuff, everything looks fine. I don't know what the problem might be...

Some code:

```
 $input = Input::all();

 Trip::create([
                'route_from'       => $input['route_from'],
                'route_to'         => $input['route_to'],
                ... adding other stuff ...
                'driver_user_id'   => Auth::user()->id
            ]);
```

When I `var_dump(Auth::user()->id)` I do get correct `int` number, which is the correctly corresponding ID of the certain user.

in the Trip model:

```
protected $hidden = [
    'id'
];
protected $fillable = [
    'route_from',
    'route_to',
    ... 
    'driver_user_id'
];
public function Trip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'driver_user_id', 'id');
}
```

in the User model:

```
public function Trips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Trip');
}
```

Comment: Can we see code? Or what framework you're using etc, just a little more info

Comment: Take a look here, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705539/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-chi#20705607

Comment: @IkoTikashi - This does not really help me. I already have the row of the certain user, created in the DB, before trying to insert the row for trip and link it to a user. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to get its `id` from `Auth::`.

Comment: Sorry, should've read more thoroughly. I can't help you here, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the gut feeling the attributes are guarded. Your code seems correct, however the error you receive originates from the database. Could you try it like this and see if it works:

```
$trip = new Trip;
$trip->unguard();
$trip->fill([
            'route_from'       => $input['route_from'],
            'route_to'         => $input['route_to'],
            ... adding other stuff ...
            'driver_user_id'   => Auth::user()->id
        ]);
$trip->save();
```

Using the `create` method on the model makes it difficult to debug what is happening.

Comment: Okay, that worked! Can you elaborate a bit, please, what was the problem with the trip being guarded? Do I necessarily need to `unguard` the whole `Trip` object, because it has the `id` field in it.. and it is sensitive data? Could I put the `driver_user_id` field in `hidden`, because it's sensitive data? And what was going on in general in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you've used $fillable to make attributes accessible (see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent). However knowing from past experience it seems to misbehave. So I always instantiate the object first, unguard, fill, reguard and save.. Also unguarding only seems effective on the current object level.

Comment: Upon further inspection of the code, your object is not totally guarded otherwise a MassAssignmentException. What exact version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.2 version.

Comment: I found this: *...if `fillable` is not specified, and the key is not listed in the `guarded` property, the framework will assume that the key can be safely mass-assigned. Sound perfectly fine and should be expected, but when we include a property that is not a field of the table, it will cause an error, because the framework will try to insert a data into a column that doesn’t exists.* in here: http://hndr.me/blog/laravel-mass-assignment-protection-blacklist-vs-whitelist/ Was helpful. :)

Comment: That is not related. Could you please post the whole $fillable and $guarded arrays and your table layout? It might be that you are trying to assign a value to a property that is not fillable or is guarded.